# How to identify Salesforce Files created by DocuSign DocuGen Templates

Tags: triggers, salesforce, docusignapi, apex, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm after a way to figure out if a Salesforce File is created by DocuSign DocuGen Template. This is needed for a ContentVersion trigger to perform certain actions.

I tried using the Name of File but it's not a reliable way to do this.

Is there a way to identify DocuSign generated Salesforce File (Content Version)?
I don't see a flag field, etc. getting updated for this purpose?

Would it be possible to update a custom flag field on Salesforce File (Content Version) for this?

Apologies if this is not the right place to post this question.

Thanks!

Comment: Would it be possible to add a suffix to the file name e.g. _DG to denote its generated by docusign? Any clues how to customise this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I know how is to ensure the filename has something unique in it that you know is the indicator that it was generated via the DocuSign Gen for Salesforce integration. The default filename options won't provide you with that option, so I would suggest considering creating a Flow or Apex trigger to rename the file after its generated. Or use Flow or Apex to modify the content version etc.
Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks @jesse! Appreciate your reply. I think this would help.